# How to minimize errors between teams working on a shared code base

Tags: architecture, database-design, team, application-design

Imagine there are two solutions that each have their model, and data layer separately, and are developed separately on different git repositories, but they both are using the same database.

Now, `team A` is working on `SolutionA` and `team B` works on `SolutionB`.
`team A` makes a breaking change on their model while they are working on a feature/x branch and they successfully deploy it to their test environment.

as you know, now `team B`'s deployment on test environment is not working correctly because the model is not the same for them and they need to update it to reflect the new changes.
I'm looking for best practices to implement them in the team so we don't face these problems.

- one solution is that teams should notify each other about their changes, but it have the cost of communications and human errors (not remembering to notify othe teams, spelling errors, naming errors etc).
- one solution is that both teams use the same model and data layer. This one could happen in two ways:

  - one way is that the model and data held in a separate solution, going this road have some drawbacks like maintaining the model, handling branching (SolutionA uses v1.1 model but SolutionB updated the model to v1.2 ...)
  - another way is that SolutionA and SolutionB merged into one big Solution and the model be inside it. Cons in this solution includes having a big solution with tons of projects in it, so going around the project will be a headache; both teams have to work on the same solution and not really isolated; and more.

The things that should be noticed here:

- we still don't have unit/integration/end2end tests to share them as suggested [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/316097/282298) (still working on that to implement them)
- we have plans to implement CI/CD after implementing tests.
- we are an start-up company so there are lot of changes, the model still is an infant!

So, is there any rule or framework or flow, anything, that solves these problems?
What big teams and companies do to prevent such errors?

### Update #1

As I thought about the problem, I realized that maybe the question is unclear.
The specific problem I described is just one of the many faces the problem could have.
Another problem could arise between front-end team (or clients) and back-end team when an API contract changed. How clients should get notified on a field name change? What about a route change? (Versioning is one solution of course)
These changes happen wildly in different places and in different forms when a project starts until it gets mature enough.

This is the main reason I posted this question in here not SO, because I'm not sure that the answer would be only technical or architectural, and I placed Team tag on the question to specify that it might be resolved by implementing a practice or flow in the team, that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I remember we already agreed that having a database as an integration point between multiple clients is a terrible, terrible idea. So maybe you should try fixing that problem first.

Comment: @Euphoric So, if we separate the databases for `teamA` and `teamB`, how it solves the problem? Imagine `teamA` just reads from `ModelA` and `teamB` reads and writes the same model, and their databases are separate. `teamA` updates `ModelA` with fields that does not exists in `teamB`'s database. This way we are moving the problem to another level (now events need to be updated between teams) rather than solving it. Or maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Once the syncronization between teams is moved outside the database, it becomes much easier to solve. It is easier to support backwards compatibility with web API than with database schema.